# How to get rid of the memory leaks in third party framework(gstreamer)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, gstreamer, gobject

I am trying to check the memory leakage of my program using Valgrind.

Note: my program contains an FSM which is polled at every 200ms.*(mentioning this because I think this might have something to do with the leaks)*

I have executed the following command and created the log file.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind_test.log ./foo
```

I see there are a lot of leaks in my program, and 90% of them are followig the same route / path as given below

```
==9890== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2,341 of 2,707
==9890==    at 0x4C30035: calloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9890==    by 0x66D96B0: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
==9890==    by 0x69CB421: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
==9890==    by 0x69CB5CA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
==9890==    by 0x69D1062: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
==9890==    by 0x6CBADD1: gst_fraction_get_type (gstvalue.c:7428)
==9890==    by 0x6CBB0B5: _priv_gst_value_initialize (gstvalue.c:7527)
==9890==    by 0x6C23B50: init_post (gst.c:777)
==9890==    by 0x66E011F: g_option_context_parse (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
==9890==    by 0x6C2462E: gst_init_check (gst.c:427)
==9890==    by 0x6C24676: gst_init (gst.c:471)
==9890==    by 0x5546CC: main (foo.cpp:97)
```

Now since this particular set of lines are repeated in the log, I suppose that polling has something to do with this, though I am not sure.

I found no path in the Valgrind log where the memories I have blocked/allocated/acquired are not freed/deallocated. It's all the third-party (GStreamer) paths. How do I analyze and remove these leaks?

Question:

```
==9890==    by 0x69CB421: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
```

What does this mean

**-------------------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------------------------**

updated scripts to suppress the false positive cases of glib mem leak

```
export G_DEBUG=gc-friendly
export G_SLICE=always-malloc
export GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW=1
export GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1

OPTS="-v --time-stamp=yes --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --leak-resolution=high --log-file=valgrind_test.log --suppressions=/path/to/glibc-2.supp --suppressions=/path/to/gst.supp"

valgrind $OPTS ./foo
```

And following is the complete log file generated:
[Complete log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JkG9VJoq7O-TNF34_LLkRRHL3Ktf6bHI/view?usp=sharing)

```
==00:00:00:25.155 3241== LEAK SUMMARY:
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==      possibly lost: 96 bytes in 1 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==    still reachable: 133,919 bytes in 1,457 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==                         length64           : 504 bytes in 12 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==                         newarray           : 1,616 bytes in 21 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241==         suppressed: 831,853 bytes in 10,770 blocks
==00:00:00:25.155 3241== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==00:00:00:25.155 3241== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

So, How can I prevent these loss?

Comment: If leaks increase over time then there's reason to react. If leaks are constant (there are only a few), then there are no reasons to react.

Comment: I checked the leaks increase as the number of cycle of state increase.

Comment: Best course of action would be to notify the third party, and work with them to fix the leak. Fixing the leak from outside is impossible in most cases. Possible remedy would be to contain the library in separate process, introduce some inter-process communication, and restart the process periodically.

Answer (score 2):

From what’s in your log, these are one-time allocations of the dynamic type information in GObject, which is used by GStreamer. They are nothing to worry about. If you run `valgrind` with `--suppressions=/usr/share/glib-2.0/valgrind/glib.supp`, you should find that they disappear. If not, and if you are sure the bug isn’t in your code, file a bug against GStreamer and work with the GStreamer developers to fix it.

---

> Question:
>
> ```
> ==9890==    by 0x69CB421: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.3)
> ```
>
> What does this mean

It means that call frame is in an unknown function in `libgobject-2.0.so.*`. This is typically caused by not having the debug symbols available for a library. You should find that if you install the debug symbols, the appropriate function name will appear in the backtrace from `valgrind`.

Comment: @Phillip Thanks for the input. **if you are sure the bug isn’t in your code** according to the logs, _none of the log specifically tells the code I have written is errorneous & everything traces backe to the mallocs/callocs from the gst library_. **these are one-time allocations** The log is repetetive, I have only pasted one of the block in the post. Please see the updated post. I have added the log file.

Comment: “The log is repetetive, I have only pasted one of the block in the post. Please see the updated post. I have added the log file” — GObject does one set of allocations for each type (roughly speaking, for each different class in your code or the code it calls). There will be several tens of these allocations, each a one-off.